# What is the modern C++ way for one class to hold a reference to data in another object?

Tags: c++, pointers, reference

I'm currently attempting modernize some of my C++ habits. One example in which I hope to modernize my code is that of object-to-object references.

Typically when I wanted one object to be able to pull information from another class, I have one the referencing class have a pointer as a member object. For example, let's say I had a 'Dog' class that I wanted to give the ability to reference an 'OutsideWorld' object. I would essentially give the Dog class a raw pointer to an OutsideWorld object.

However, the use of raw pointers in C++ seems to be fading for new alternative methods.

So my question: What is the best modern method for a class to hold a reference to another object? Is is it as simple as switching from raw pointers to smart pointers, or would it be better to declare a reference variable?

Comment: Raw observer pointers are perfectly okay in modern C++. It's the use that requires you to perform resource management on some of them that's heavily frowned upon.

Comment: Do you want a pointer to another object, or to a member of another object?

Comment: @krzaq Hmm.. That's actually  a really good point. Most of the discussion of modernizing references did have to do with resource management and avoidance of memory leaks.

Comment: @Beta It my application case, it would only be a member of another object, but I assume the question could apply to either.

Comment: This is highly opinionated, but in general proper use of `unique_ptr` and `shared_ptr` alleviates most need of manual object bookkeeping.

Comment: I'm flagging this question as primarily opinion based. This isn't a terrible question, but there isn't real _one_ answer to this.

Comment: It depends on the nature of the reference.

Comment: " ... wanted one object to be able to pull information from another class" (I suppose you mean from another class instance).  See Martin Fowler.  "Tell-Don't-Ask is a principle that helps people remember that object-orientation is about bundling data with the functions that operate on that data. It reminds us that rather than asking an object for data and acting on that data, we should instead tell an object what to do. This encourages to move behavior into an object to go with the data."